# is there a way to capture a exact error message in ps catch block?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql, powershell-3.0

is there any way to capture specific error message while this call to store that error message in sql table  ?

```
function Get-SqlData {
param([string]$serverName=$(throw 'serverName is required.'), [string]$databaseName=$(throw 'databaseName is required.'),
  [string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'))

    try {
        Write-Verbose "Get-SqlData serverName:$serverName databaseName:$databaseName query:$query"
        $connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection( "Data Source=$serverName;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
        $adapter = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter ($query, $connection)
        $table = new-object system.data.datatable
        [void]$adapter.Fill($table) #| out-null
        $table
    } catch {
        write-host $Server
        write-host 'Connection issue'
    }
} 

$Query = "set nocount on; SELECT CASE WHEN Is_Clustered = 1 THEN SQLClusterName ELSE ServerName END FROM Server_Master_List WHERE Is_Monitored = 1    "
$Servers = sqlcmd -b -S XYZ-XYZ -d DBA -h -1 -Q $Query -W

$sqltbl = @()

foreach($Server in $Servers) { $sqltbl += Get-SqlData $Server 'master' $qry }
#$sqltbl

<#Insert data from Powershell variable to SQL table #>
$connectionString = "Server=$env:ComputerName;Database=DBA;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: `server\instancename`. This is no different in PowerShell than it is anywhere else. Also, consider just using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from the `SqlServer` module rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I did not understand, Server_Master_List in this table entry for server is like server\instancename like this still its not working

Comment: "server\instancename" should work. I don't think the issue is related to PS. Can you connect with the same specification in SSMS?

Comment: Yeah its working I recall it, is there a way to capture error message in ps if connection breaks

Comment: In a catch block `$_` will be a reference to the Exception, which will have all the details.  For a SqlException it will have a `.Errors` collection containing possibly multiple error messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can tell PowerShell to only catch certain types of exceptions.

For example...

```
$serverName = 'SOMERANDOMSERVER'
$databaseName = 'DoesntMatter'
$query = 'SELECT 1'

try {
  $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection ("Data Source=$serverName;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
  $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($query, $connection)
  $table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
  [void]$adapter.Fill($table)
  $table
} catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] {
  'CAUGHT A SQL EXCEPTION!!'
} catch {
  'Caught some other type of exception'
}
```

However, if you want to get further into the details, you'll need to start parsing the exceptions themselves.

And that's where this leads me to ask...why do you need to do this? A query with bad syntax, a query that throws an error, an unavailable server...those will all return a `SqlException`. Do you plan on implementing something which handles each of these exceptions in a particular way?

---

Personal opinion:

Any time I see someone starting to write code in PowerShell for running SQL queries, my first question is...Are you trying to build some sort of maintenance/utility script where it's okay to utilize existing community modules? If so, you need to look up [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/). It's a PowerShell module that is packed with cmdlets that handle all this stuff for you. For example, you've basically just written their cmdlet called `Invoke-DbaQuery`

Another tip...learn about [advanced parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) in PowerShell. You can add various checks against parameters to ensure they are mandatory, and even include verification checks to ensure the parameter values are valid prior to executing the script. That would allow you to properly implement required parameters, and you can remove the hack you've used here.